# transforming a list of lists of int to list of int in java 8

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

I want to use java 8 to write a stream processing chain, and in a specific step, I want to stream `List<List<Integer>>` and get `List<Integer>` of the sums of each `List`.

e.g. `[[1,2],[1,3,4],[10,11]] ---> [3, 8, 21]`

What's the function I need to use/ write to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should map every value of the original `List` which is `List<Integer>` to the `Integer` representing its sum. This can be done, for example, using `list.stream().mapToInt(x -> x).sum()`. So the whole problem can be solved in the following way:

```
List<Integer> result = input.stream()
                            .map(list -> list.stream().mapToInt(x -> x).sum())
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```